# Tabhost with fragments recreating views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I'm working on app which main view is activity with tabhost. Tabhost contains fagments. The problem I'm facing is that whenever i switch from one tab to the another the fragment is recreated. This is not the expected behaviour. When user fill some data in first tab then go to second and back to first one all the filled data disapper. Is there a way to prevent tabhost from recreating views or should I use viewPager instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you used  `.replace()` method for replace `Fragment` Container layout it's internally first called `.remove()` and then add `.add()` so your `onCreateview(...)` called again.

Best way is instead of replace `Fragment` Container layout try to used `ft.detach(Fragment);` and  `ft.attach(Fragment);`

What it does?

> ft.detach(Fragment);// Detach your Fragment from FragmentTransaction

and

> ft.attach(Fragment)// Attach fragment from FragmentTransaction

below i show you one demo:

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
    AndroidFragment myfragment= (AndroidFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("fragment1");
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    if(fragment==null){
    /** Create Fragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AndroidFragment(), "fragment1");
     }else{
    /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
    ft.attach(myfragment);
     }
```

For more information take look in this [Blog](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/)

Comment: thanks for answer, it looks like I have to take care of switching tabs by myself, will try it later and accept answer if works

Comment: @Greg exactly. I faced the same issue in past and i have solved by using this. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I looks like in my case there is something else that makes fragment to be recreated. I'm using FragmentTabHost not TabHost and as you can see in source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.java there is already implemented detach/attach functionality